# Lambda function not triggered by dynamodb update: Key Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am attempting to load a simple transactions.txt table into a S3 bucket where a Lambda function reads the file and populates DynamoDB tables for Customers and Transactions.  This all works fine.  However, I also have a Lambda function that is supposed to read the Transactions table as they populate the table and sum up the transaction totals by customer and insert them into another DynamoDB table--TransactionTotal.

My TotalNotifier Lambda function throws a "KeyError" regarding a "New Image".  I believe the code is fine, and I have tried changing the type of Streams from 'New and Old' to just 'New' for the Transactions table and still encounter same error.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json, boto3

# Connect to SNS
sns = boto3.client('sns')
alertTopic = 'HighBalanceAlert'
snsTopicArn = [t['TopicArn'] for t in sns.list_topics()['Topics'] if t['TopicArn'].endswith(':' + alertTopic)][0]

# Connect to DynamoDB
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
transactionTotalTableName = 'TransactionTotal'
transactionsTotalTable = dynamodb.Table(transactionTotalTableName);

# This handler is executed every time the Lambda function is triggered
def lambda_handler(event, context):

  # Show the incoming event in the debug log
  print("Event received by Lambda function: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

  # For each transaction added, calculate the new Transactions Total
  for record in event['Records']:
    customerId = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['CustomerId']['S']
    transactionAmount = int(record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['TransactionAmount']['N'])

    # Update the customer's total in the TransactionTotal DynamoDB table
    response = transactionsTotalTable.update_item(
      Key={
        'CustomerId': customerId
  },
  UpdateExpression="add accountBalance :val",
  ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ':val': transactionAmount
  },
  ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Here is a sample error from the CloudWatch log:

```
'NewImage': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler
customerId = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['CustomerId']['S']
KeyError: 'NewImage'
```

Comment: You should check that the event_name is a "MODIFY" before processing the records. "REMOVE", "INSERT" events are also coming in the stream

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Oluwafemi's comment, you're likely experiencing this error when receiving a REMOVE event. Regardless of whether your stream is new and old images, or just new, you won't receive a NEW_IMAGE on a REMOVE event, since there is no new image. Check out the [example events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update) on aws docs.

A check on the value of `record['eventName']` should solve the issue.